# Swagger 'GET' request always returns as text/html Accept type on response and NOT application/json

Tags: javascript, api, rest, swagger

I have a swagger tag document using the Swagger UI that always returns text/html but it should return application/json.  The POST requests and every other type returns application/json but this particular GET request does not.  The service end point code is correct.  And if I change the request to POST it does return as application/json.   So it is just type GET within swagger which does not return the correct type.  Any thoughts how to correct the call within the UI to use the application/json?

This is swagger version 2.1.4 that was downloaded recently from the swagger site.

```
"/bankName": {
    "get": {
        "summary": "Bank Name Search",
        "description": "Bank Name Search, input routing number to return bank name",                
        "consumes": [    
            "application/json"
        ],    
        "produces": [
            "application/json"
        ],                                 
        "parameters": [
            {
                "in": "query",                          
                "name": "routingNumber",
                "description": "Input Bank Routing Number",
                "required": true,   
                "type": "string",                           
            }
        ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "An array",
                "schema": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "errorInfo": { 
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/ErrorInfo"                   
                        },
                        "bankName": {
                            "type": "string",                                   
                        }
                    }
               }                        
            },
            "400": {
                "description": "Invalid Request Input supplied"                         
            },                  
            "500": {
                "description": "General Unexpected Error"
            }                       
        }
    }
}
```

> Accept:application/json
>
> Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
>
> Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
>
> Cache-Control:no-cache
>
> Connection:keep-alive
>
> Host:localhost:9086
>
> Origin:http://localhost:9086
>
> Pragma:no-cache
>
> Referer:http://localhost:9086/swagger/index.html

Here is the Java code Spring Restful definition:

```
@RequestMapping(value="bankName",
    method=RequestMethod.GET,
    produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Comment: Can I see your Swagger index.html code? Also can you share the request headers that you see in the browser when you make the GET call?

Comment: why your get has "consumes"?

Comment: The index.html is on the website from the most recent download.  The get has consumes as copy past but I can remove.

Comment: I added the request headers, I notice that the 'content-type' is not defined.  When I look at the real code, the content-type is defined and I get json back.

Comment: GET requests do not have content-type as they do not have body.

Comment: Well there is the swagger definition and backend definition, why isn't it working.  Everything is JSON, there is no reference to text/html

Comment: I guess there is problem in your API response. Can you check if your `GET` API response content-type is application/json?

Comment: Please elaborate how a request in the Swagger UI can "return" anything and what you mean by "correcting the call within the UI". Since the Swagger UI will only display the spec nicely and allow to send requests accordingly, but doesn't control what is returned by the server, it doesn't make sense to me at the moment. Is the problem that the server returns the wrong content type or Swagger UI just displays it wrong? If you, for example, manually use the CURL command the UI creates in a shell (add `-i` param for headers), what is returned then? Can you copy the CURL command and its result here?

Comment: What happens if you just say produces = "application/json" ? Instead of that MediaType object you are using? What if you change that temporally to application/xml does XML get sent back?

Comment: It looks like it is corrected.  I think it was the backend and 'consumes' had  json.  By changing that.  the issue was corrected.

Comment: @BerlinBrown I can recommend the Firefox plugin http requester for these sorts of things, [requester](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/httprequester/) it rules out quickly the front end code and you can fire requests to the back end to check if they are misbehaving. Saves a huge amount of time and cuts out wasted testing.

Comment: Swagger UI is just a tool for designing and documenting an API.  It seems like the problem may be in the framework/code where your API is implemented.  Do you have two functions where one handles the POST request and a second handles the GET request?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
"/bankName": {
    "get": {
        "summary": "Bank Name Search",
        "description": "Bank Name Search, input routing number to return bank name",                
        "consumes": [    
            "application/json"
        ],    
        "produces": [
            "application/json"
        ],                                 
        "parameters": [
            {
                "in": "query",                          
                "name": "routingNumber",
                "description": "Input Bank Routing Number",
                "required": true,   
                "type": "string",                           
            }
        ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "An array",
                "content": {
                    "application/json": {
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "errorInfo": { 
                                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ErrorInfo"                   
                                },
                                "bankName": {
                                    "type": "string",                                   
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "400": {
                "description": "Invalid Request Input supplied"                         
            },                  
            "500": {
                "description": "General Unexpected Error"
            }                       
        }
    }
}
```